# Vuelidate - validating login and signup forms, combined in a single form

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm using [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/) for Vue3 and I've created a single form in a modal that serves as both login and registration form.

When you click the Register button, the form displays 4 fields - username, email, password and repeat password. Clicking the Login button only displays the email and password fields from the same form.

How can I validate the Register form separately from the Login form when we have 2 overlapping fields used in both forms - email and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply share rules by extending them in the broader case:

```
const loginRules = {
  // [...]
};

const registerRules = {
  ...loginRules, 
  // [...]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using different registration rules for the same form. Here is how I did it:
```
let loginRules = {
  userEmail: { required, email },
  password: { required },
};

let registrationRules = {
  userName: { required },
  userEmail: { required, email },
  password: { required },
  repeat: { required },
};
let rules = {};
let fields = {};
if (props.isLogin) {
  rules = loginRules;
  fields = { userEmail, password };
} else {
  rules = registrationRules;
  fields = { userEmail, password, userName, repeat };
}
const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, fields);
```